# Using Matrices to Move Triangle without GL OpenGL matrix functions

Tags: c++, opengl, matrix

I don't know how to do this without OpenGL matrix functions.

> Transform the triangle by multiplying  each vertex position by a 2D
>   affine scaling, rotation, or translation  matrix as specified below
>   through keyboard input.
>
> Keyboard input:
>
> ```
> 's' key, scale by 1.1 units in X and Y
> 'r' key, rotate clockwise (in XY plane) by 2.0 degrees
> 't' key, translate 0.1 unit in X and Y
> 'q' key, quit program
> ```
>
> **You may NOT use OpenGL matrix functions such as glScale, glTranslate, or glRotate to perform your transformations.**

This is what I have so far... when I build the program the triangle doesn't move, but I get random numbers after pressing some keys so I know it's doing something:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <math.h>
#include <GLUT/glut.h>

void myInit();
void myDraw();
void keyboard( unsigned char, int, int );
float sum;


float theta = 3.14;
int k = 0;

float cVert[3][2]= 
{ 
  -1.0, -1.0, 
  1.0, -1.0,
  0.0, 1.0
};

float triVert[3][2] = 
{
    -1.0, -1.0, 
    1.0, -1.0,
    0.0, 1.0
};

float rotVert[3][3] =
{
  1,0,0,
  0, cos(theta), -sin(theta),
  0, sin(theta), cos(theta)
};

float scaleVert[3][2] =
{
  1.1, 0.0,
  0.0, 1.1, 
  0.0, 0.0
};

int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{   
  // Initialize window system 
  glutInit( &argc, argv );
  glutInitDisplayMode( GLUT_SINGLE | GLUT_RGB );
  glutInitWindowSize( 640, 480 );
  glutCreateWindow( "Lab 4" );

  // Initialize graphics 
  myInit();

  // Callbacks
  glutDisplayFunc( myDraw );
    glutKeyboardFunc( keyboard );

    // Event loop 
  glutMainLoop();
}

// Initialize drawing
void myInit()
{
  // Background color 
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);

  // 2D world projection
  glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
  glLoadIdentity();
  gluOrtho2D( -10.0, 10.0, -10.0, 10.0 );
}

// Display callback 
void myDraw()
{
    // Clear the screen 
  glClearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
  glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

  // // Draw triangle in initial position
  // glColor3f( 1.0, 0.0, 0.0 );
  // glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
     //  glVertex2f( triVert[0][0], triVert[0][1] );
        // glVertex2f( triVert[1][0], triVert[1][1] );
        // glVertex2f( triVert[2][0], triVert[2][1] );
  // glEnd();

  // Draw triangle in new position here
  glBegin( GL_LINE_LOOP );
    glColor3f( 0.0, 1.0, 0.0 );
    glVertex2f(cVert[0][0], cVert[0][1]);
    glVertex2f(cVert[1][0], cVert[1][1]);
    glVertex2f(cVert[2][0], cVert[2][1]);
    cout << cVert[3][2] << " ";
  glEnd();

  // Execute draw commands 
  glFlush();
}

// Keyboard callback 
void keyboard( unsigned char key, int x, int y )
{
  // Process keys 
  switch (key)
    {
  case 's': //scale by 1.1 units in X and Y
      for(k=0;k<3;++k)
       {
        cVert[3][2] = cVert[3][2]+(scaleVert[3][2]*triVert[3][2]);
        cout << cVert[3][2]<<" ";
        }
      break;
  case 'r': //rotate clockwise (in XY plane) by 2.0 degrees
       for(k=0;k<3;++k)
       {
        cVert[3][2] = cVert[3][2]+(rotVert[3][3]*triVert[3][2]);
        theta = theta + 2.0;
         cout << cVert[3][2]<<" ";
         cout << theta << " ";
        }
      break;
  case 't': //translate 0.1 unit in X and Y
      break;
    case 'q':                       // exit program
      exit(1);
      break;
    }

  // Redraw the scene 
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: The assignment tells you exactly what to do. You must build the respective transformation matrices and multiply your vertices with them. Write a function to do 3×3 matrix multiplications and a few helpers to build the right transformation matrices. Then use those.

Comment: I'm not exactly clear on that, I thought that's what I was doing then, multiplying the matrices by those that represent transform or rotation or scaling.

Comment: I see some loops iterating over an varible k, but that variable is never used as index into the matrices. Also you should not paste the matrix multiplication verbatim-inline. Write functions `mat3x3_mul(mat3x3 out, mat3x3 a, mat3x3b)` and `mat3x3_mul_vec3(vec3 out, mat3x34 M, vec3 v)` and use those. You may want to look at my linmath.h on how to do it: https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h/blob/master/linmath.h – doesn't contain mat3x3 code but the multiplication rules are the same regardless of the dimension of the matrix.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of this program is undefined, so no wonder you get "random" numbers.

```
    cVert[3][2] = cVert[3][2]+(scaleVert[3][2]*triVert[3][2]);
```

This does *not* perform matrix addition or multiplication. 
It merely adds the product of one element of one matrix and one element
of another matrix to one element of a third matrix. 
Or at least it *would* do so if any of those elements were actually in any of those
matrices, but actually the bottom right element of `cVert` is `cVert[2][1]`
--remember, C++ numbers rows and columns starting from zero, so the declaration 
`float cVert[3][2]` says that the first index has 3 values (0, 1, or 2)
and the second has 2 values (0 or 1)--
and similarly for the other two matrices.
Your program didn't crash, so all those locations are in accessible memory somewhere,
but they are accessing completely different data than you intended.

As already noted in a comment, matrix addition and multiplication are not built into
the C++ language itself.  You are clearly meant to write the source code for them
yourself.  You may want to make sure you have reviewed how matrix multiplication
is defined--a straightforward addition function for matrices has two nested loops,
but a straightforward multiplication function has three nested loops.

Another problem is that `rotVert` is initialized statically using the previous
static definition of `theta`.
In itself there is nothing wrong with this (though not much good in it either),
but understand that changes you make to the value of `theta` later 
do *not* automatically propagate back to `rotVert`.
The initializers of `rotVert` in the curly braces are evaluated *once* before your
`main` function runs, their numeric values are copied into `rotVert`, and then
that particular piece of code is never used again.

Your rotations will also be a bit crazy if you aren't more careful about your angle units.
You know that `sin(theta)` and `cos(theta)` will interpret `theta` as a number of radians.
If you call the trig functions exactly that way (with parameter `theta`), then
`theta = theta + 2.0;` will add two *radians* (about 114 degrees), not 2 degrees,
to your angle of rotation.  Either figure out what 2 degrees is in radians,
or convert your degree-measured angle to radians every time you pass it to a trig function.

(The problem with the angle units is currently masked by the fact that the value
of `theta` never actually get used in your rotation matrix after static initialization
of your program, so you'll have to fix the matrix-initialization problem before you can
really see whether the angle units are working correctly.)